# pictureBox initial image and error image

Tags: c#

In my C# form I want to set a minimum of 5 characters in my textBox and show the error image or the initial image at the same time. If the characters is less than 5 then the picturebox will show the x image but if it is greater than 5 then it will show the check image. Can someone help me with this?

Here is my Code:

```
if (textBox1.TextLength > 5)
{
     pictureBox1.InitialImage = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code to change pictureBox image by text length as below:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.TextLength > 5)
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"ximagelocalion";                
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"checkimagelocalion";
        }
    }
```